# SoapHeaders are not passed in the SoapMessage to CXF service in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I am not getting the SoapHeader tags in the Soap message in the cxf service invoked. My current code is as below:

I have defined a cxf:cxfEndpoint for the service:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="testService" address="${testserviceurl}"
    serviceClass="com.test.service.class" wsdlURL="test.wsdl"
    endpointName="ns:test" serviceName="ns:TestService"
    xmlns:ns="target.name.space.of.the.service">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

And then before invoking my cxf endpoint, I have set the SoapHeader as:

```
CxfPayload<SoapHeader> payload = exchange.getIn().getBody(
        CxfPayload.class);
List<SoapHeader> headers = payload.getHeaders();
SoapHeader header = new SoapHeader(new QName("HeaderName"), "Test");
headers.add(header);
```

I have also tried the approach:

```
List<SoapHeader> soapHeaders = CastUtils.cast((List<?>) exchange
        .getIn().getHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST));
if (soapHeaders == null) {
    // we just create a new soap headers in case the header is null
    soapHeaders = new ArrayList<SoapHeader>();
}
SoapHeader header = new SoapHeader(new QName("HeaderName"),
        "Test");
header.setDirection(Direction.DIRECTION_OUT);
soapHeaders.add(header);
```

Can anyone please help on what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you make any synchronous request through cxf client. It uses jdk's Http connection client to communicate over http.
As per this [jira defect](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6611) jdk does't allow to set header.
If you want to set headers you can do it by setting VM parameter

```
sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true
```

If you use cxf in async mode it uses apache's HttpAsyncClient. This allows you to set the request headers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Vijendra, thanks for your response. I am able to set the request headers, but the issue is with the SOAP Headers under the tag '<soapenv:Header>' in the payload message.